# Rails ActiveRecord joins and includes in the same query?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I always assumed that I should use either `.joins` or `.includes`, but not both in the same query.

Say we have a schema with 3 tables in the database.

I have an `User` model.

`User` has_many `Contact`

`Contact` has_many `ContactEvent`

Please take notice that some `Contacts` have 0 `Contactevents`, some have many !

### Goal

I want to get a specific `User`, get each of his `Contacts` and calculate how many `ContactEvent` each `Contact` has.

### First attempt was something like this:

`user = User.find_by_id(1)`

`user.contacts.map{|contact| contact.contact_events.size}`

This generates a quazillion queries and takes a huge load on memory (it has to load all 50k Contacts a user has in memory and then starts a query for each contact).

Very bad for performance since it loads all `Contacts`, totally not called for because, for example, from the 50k `Contacts` only 3k have `ContactEvents`.

### Second attempt:

`Contact.joins(:contact_events).where("user_id = 1").uniq.map{|c| c.contact_events.size}`

This was much faster, because it first only loads `Contacts` that already have `ContactEvents`, but still takes like 10 seconds, and there's a HUGE number of queries in the console trying to get the `contact_events` for each `contact`. Example: `(7.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contact_events WHERE contact_events.contact_id = 2052447`

### Third is the charm ... but is it correct ?

Since I noticed the previous attempt was making an extra query for each :contact_events, I had a hint to use `.includes`

But if I simply replaced `.joins` with `.includes`, I noticed it would not return only `Contacts` that had `ContactEvents`, it would return all `Contacts`.

I finally managed to get what I wanted by using the following line:

`Contact.joins(:contact_events).where("user_id = 1").includes(:contact_events).map{|c| c.contact_events.size}`

This is ultra fast, is only one query, takes less then a second.

Is this the correct approach ? Use a .joins and .includes for the same query ?

Answer (score 0):

You have options to get more efficient to count your `contact_events`.

Option 1:

The use of `LEFT {OUTER} JOIN` means that if `contact` does not have `contact_events` will show 0. You can use `INNER JOIN` when you think that you want to disappear `contact` when there is no `contact_events`.

```
Contact.select("contacts.*, COUNT(contact_events.contact_id) as contact_events_count")
.join("LEFT JOIN contact_events ON contacts.id = contact_events.contact_id")
.group("contacts.id")
```

Option 2:

You can use [counter_cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache)

```
# Contact
has_many :contact_events

# Contact Event
belongs_to :contact, counter_cache: true
```

Finaly, to get counter size you can call by:

**Controller**

```
@contacts = Contact.all
```

**View**

```
@contacts.each do |contact|
  contact.contact_events_count
end
```

I hope this help you.